# Can't deploy ASP.net core RC2 targeting net451 or net46 to Azure Web App

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

I can't seem to be able to deploy my asp.net core RC2 app to Azure when I target the net451 or net46 framework.

When I try to reach my application I get the following error

> The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process.

Everything works when I deploy to my local IIS.

The Azure logger gives me

> Failed to start process with commandline '%LAUNCHER_PATH% %LAUNCHER_ARGS%', Error Code = '0x80070002'.

I tried replacing `%LAUNCHER_PATH%` for `dotnet` and `%LAUNCHER_ARGS%` for `myapp.exe` in the web.config but still the same error occur.

Here is my project.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-final"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net46": {}
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "gcServer": true
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Check the event log counterpart and see if there is anything interesting there. Turn on logging by setting `stdoutLogEnabled` to `true` and `stdoutLogPath` to `\\?\%home%\LogFiles\stdout` and see what's in the log. Take a look at my post that provide steps to troubleshoot https://blog.3d-logic.com/2016/06/08/running-asp-net-core-applications-with-iis-and-antares/

Comment: Thanks Pawel, I've edited my question to show the result of your suggestion.

Comment: Did you try to download again the publish profile?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that updating my web.config to specify the processPath did the trick.

I also had to delete the previous publish attempts for it to work properly.

```
<aspNetCore processPath=".\myapp.exe" arguments="" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" stdoutLogEnabled="true"  stdoutLogFile="\\?\%home%\LogFiles\stdout"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

With the same symptoms I checked the logs as @Pawel suggested.
The logs contained FileNotFoundException which was resolved by adding two dependencies to `project.json`.

```
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher": "4.0.0-rc2-24027",
  "System.IO.FileSystem": "4.0.1-rc2-24027"
},
```

The issue is [reported here](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/801)

Answer (score 0):

Azure doesn't support net461 and use better net451.

```
"scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
```

**Publishing SkyIsTheLimit for .NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1/win7-x64**